# PHP file listing multiple file extensions

Tags: php

Here is my current code:

```
$files = glob("*.jpg");
```

This works fine. However, I am wanting to list other image types, such as .png, gif etc.

Can I please have some help to modify this above code to get it working. I have tried the following with no success:

```
$files = glob("*.jpg","*.png","*.gif");

$files = glob("*.jpg,*.png,*.gif);
```

And other variations...

Answer (score 155, accepted):

```
$files = glob("*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: Just be careful when using GLOB_BRACE regarding spaces around the comma:
{jpg,png,gif} works as expected, but
{jpg, png, gif} with a leading space, will only match the former as expected but not the latter.

Comment: Just a heads up. This is case sensitive, so if your given files with .JPG it won't work.  You could  use `$files = glob("*.{[jJ][pP][gG],[pP][nN][gG],[gG][iI][fF]}", GLOB_BRACE);`

Comment: @hidden-username this doesnt work. it seems to get only the last [] of each group, so `*.[gG],*.[gG],*.[fF]` in that case. probably brace and [] doesnt work together.

Comment: Another point to be careful about: From the official PHP docs:
Note: The GLOB_BRACE flag is not available on some non GNU systems, like Solaris.
So depending on the server environment you are running, you may be unable to use GLOB_BRACE

Comment: @hidden-username Why complicate things? Keep it simple: `"*.{jpg,png,gif,JPG,PNG,GIF}"`

Comment: I had spaces after the commas, and so fail until I removed the spaces. i.e. extensions list for GLOB is white space sensitive.

Comment: @WackGet because [jJ][pP][gG] will catch Jpg, jPg, jpG,, JpG and any other case sensitive variation without having to type them one by one.

Answer (score 6):

## 05 2021

This is just an expansion of @Jeroen answer.

### Somethings to keep in mind

#### 'flag' is Important

Since you are using curly brackets, keep in mind `GLOB_BRACE` is required. Without the flag, you will get a empty array of items

```
$files = glob("*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

#### Sorting

This will also help you to sort the files in the way you have written.
The sorting below is based on the order of extensions inside the curly bracket.

```
$files = glob("*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
xx.jpg
xx.jpg
xx.png
xx.gif
xx.gif

$files = glob("*.{gif,jpg,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
xx.gif
xx.gif
xx.jpg
xx.jpg
xx.png
```

#### + Bonus

If you have to list out all the files but without a folder, you can use this

```
$files = glob("*.{*}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a much easier solution than using GLOB_BRACE and it is case insensitive:

```
$files = array_filter(glob('path/*.*'), function ($filename) { return preg_match('/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i', $filename); });
sort($files);
```

Or you could simply do it like this:

```
$files = preg_grep('/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i', glob('path/*.*'));
sort($files);
```

Just my two cents, hope it helps anyone who ends up here.

Comment: How to convert your code to ignore index.php file? I want list all php and html files except index.php file

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

```
$availableImageFormats = [
"png",
"jpg",
"jpeg",
"gif"];
$searchDir = /*yourDir*/;
$imageExtensions = "{";
foreach ($availableImageFormats as $extension) {
    $extensionChars = str_split($extension);
    $rgxPartial = null;
    foreach ($extensionChars as $char) {
        $rgxPartial .= "[".strtoupper($char).strtolower($char)."]";
    }
    $rgxPartial .= ",";
    $imageExtensions .= $rgxPartial;
};
$imageExtensions .= "}";
glob($searchDir."/*.".$imageExtensions, GLOB_BRACE)
```

With this you can create an array of all the extensions you are looking for without worrying of improper case use.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I just needed this for my own project. I made a converter from array to string.

```php
function whitelistToBrace($whitelist) {
  $str = "{";
  $whitelist = !empty($whitelist) ? $whitelist : ['*'];

  foreach($whitelist as $extension) {
    $str .= '*.' . strtolower($extension) . ',';
  };

  $str = substr($str, 0, -1) . '}';

  return $str;
}
```

**Usage**

```php
$whitelist = [
  'png',
  'jpg'
];

// glob('my/path/*.{*.png,*.jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);
$glob = glob('my/path/' . whitelistToBrace($whitelist), GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($glob);
```