# Show only images inside specific folder with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to show only images files from a specific folder with php and try so:

```
$dirname = "users/".trim($_GET['nome']);
    $files = array();
    if (is_dir($dirname)) {} else {mkdir($dirname, 0777);}
    $dir = opendir($dirname);
        //while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
        while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
            //if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
            if($file == '.' || $file == '..' || strpos($file,'jpg') == false){
                continue;
            }
            $files[] = array('file' => 'http://www.lavorirapidi.it/public/users/'.trim($_GET['nome']).'/'.$file, 'name' => $file);
        }
    echo json_encode($files);
```

But I notice that I view only jpg small case! If I remove

```
|| strpos($file,'jpg') == false
```

I view also subdirectory!
My question is: is it possible view only jpg, png, gif not case sensitive?

Comment: Where are we with this question? Does any answer solves your problem?

Answer (score 2):

There's already a built in function for that. [stripos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

```
if (stripos($file, '.jpg') !== false || stripos($file, '.png') !== false) {
    //$file should be an image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) with the GLOB_BRACE flag to match multiple extension and bracket to make it case insensitive

```
    $dirname = "users/".trim($_GET['nome']);
    $files = array();
    if (is_dir($dirname)) {} else {mkdir($dirname, 0777);}
    $fileNames = glob("*.{[jJ][pP][gG],[pP][nN][gG],[gG][iI][fF]}", GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($fileNames as $fileName){
         $files[] = array('file' => 'http://www.lavorirapidi.it/public/users/'.trim($_GET['nome']).'/'.$fileName, 'name' => $fileName);
    }
    echo json_encode($files);
```

Comment: You shouldn't really post code only answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/246338

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Sorry just edited my post with all the explanation

Comment: @My1 claims (here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10591546/2943403 ) that this BRACE pattern does not work as expected.  ...I haven't tested it, so I cannot confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and everything is that easy:

```
<?php

    $dirname = "users/" . trim($_GET['nome']);
    if (!is_dir($dirname))
        mkdir($dirname, 0777);

    $files = glob($dirname . "/*.*");
    //filter all non images out of the files array
    $files = array_filter($files, function($v){
        return in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($v)["extension"]), ["jpg", "png", "gif"]);
    });
    //modify array to expected output
    $files = array_map(function($v){
        return ["file" => "http://www.lavorirapidi.it/public/users/" . trim($_GET['nome']) . "/" . $v, "name" => $v];
    }, $files);

    echo json_encode($files);

?>
```

Example array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => http://www.lavorirapidi.it/public/users/test/test/1.Jpg
            [name] => test/1.Jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => http://www.lavorirapidi.it/public/users/test/test/2.JPG
            [name] => test/2.JPG
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [file] => http://www.lavorirapidi.it/public/users/test/test/3.pNg
            [name] => test/3.pNg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [file] => http://www.lavorirapidi.it/public/users/test/test/4.jpG
            [name] => test/4.jpG
        )

)
```