# Glob filter format with regular expression

Tags: php

I can view all `jpg` images in a folder using the function [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

```
$list = glob('../uploads/images/*.jpg');
usort(
   $list,
   create_function('$b,$a', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);')
);
foreach($list as $file)
{
    echo '<img src="../uploads/images/'.basename($file).'"/>';  

}
```

How do I get regular expression in the file format? I tried to accept jpg and JPG but did not work: `$list = glob('../uploads/images/*.("%.+.[jJ][pP][eE]?[gG]$%i")');`

Comment: `filemtime`, `fileatime`, `filectime` afaik

Comment: @Gisele above link best answer is dated 2008. I have added a similar [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35925596/3294262) with use of anonymous function, introduced in PHP in 2010.

Comment: @fusion3k Thanks this worked for me. How do I get regular expression in the file format? I tried to accept `jpg` and `JPG` but did not work: `$list = glob('../uploads/images/*.("%.+.[jJ][pP][eE]?[gG]$%i")');`

Comment: I updated my doubts to not be a duplicate question. Please see

Comment: @Gisele http://stackoverflow.com/a/10591546/3294262

Comment: hahaha again a duplicate question. Thanks it worked. duplicate questions should be excluded?