# Assigning unique names for each option in a foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, syntax, uniqueidentifier

Good morning,

I have the following form:

```
<form name="changeImage" method="post" style="padding-bottom: 5%; border-bottom: 1px dotted black; margin-bottom: 5%;" >
    <select name="change[]" id="change" form="changeImage" style="width: 97%;">
        <?php 
            foreach(glob('images/backgrounds/*.*') as $filename){
                echo '<option value="'.$filename.'">'.$filename.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="changeBGimage" id="changeBGimage" value="Change BG Image" style="width: 97%;" />

    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['changeBGimage'])) {
            $updateBG = "UPDATE grow_backgroundImage SET filePath = '".$_POST['change']."'";
            $updateBGQuery = $conn->query($updateBG);
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

I am having trouble assigning a unique value to $filename. 
After some research, it looks this can be done with either a hidden element or an array. I would like to use an array, but am unsure of how to do this.

Currently, when the form is submitted, it is being submitted to the database correctly, however all values are equal to the last value in the foreach loop.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `$updateBG = "UPDATE grow_backgroundImage SET filePath = '".$_POST['change']."'";` instead

Comment: Side note: You realize that you'll be updating your entire database like that. Unless that's what you want to do.

Comment: *"however all values are equal to the last value in the foreach loop"* - Right; just as I mentioned above; you've no `WHERE` clause.

Comment: another thing; `<option>` doesn't use the name attribute, only `<select>` does. I'm voting this one out.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus $updateBG = "UPDATE grow_backgroundImage SET filePath = '".$_POST['change']."'"; is not working, because change has not been created as an array

Comment: arrays need `[]`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner there is only 1 entry in the database, this is fine.

Comment: @CodyMacLeod Based on your code, it should be working correctly. Have you tried submitting the form?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus i have attempted submitting the form. 
It echos:

UPDATE grow_backgroundImage SET filePath = ''1

Comment: Change needs to be turned into an array, but i am unsure how to do this

Comment: Try `<select name="change[]"` and remove the name attribute from the `<option>`. But it's unsure what it is exactly you want to do with all those files though.

Comment: I am really struggling to be sympathetic here, bud. You completely lack even the most basic debugging techniques. Try this: comment out the update code and do `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';` and add the output to your question.

Comment: I might have been wrong about the `<select name="change[]"` here...  I take it that you have different files showing up in the options, right? If so, then you'd need to assign that variable to the POST array and add an `action=""` to `<form...>`. The missing `action` could be an issue.  The id's suggest you're using JS elsewhere not shown, is this the case? I'll test your code to a certain extent and see what I can come up with. Once you've gotten the right echo'd value, you'd be in business.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus i have updated the code above to reflect your changes. 
 after commenting out the code and using your echo, it returns: 
Array
(
    [changeBGimage] => Change BG Image
)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i am not using any JS outside of this code. You are correct in regards to the options being different file paths.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That did it. 
When I was researching select statements, I was under the impression that the select attribute had to be assigned to a specific form. I really do appreciate your assistance.

Comment: You can either add `id="changeImage"` to your form tag because you specified `<select form="changeImage"` or just remove `form="changeImage"` from the `<select>` tag.

Comment: yeah, I just tested this also, and it's all those id's mucking this all up and extra name attributes.

Comment: If you plan on taking this live, do use a prepared statement for this. Otherwise your db will be compromised as it's open to an sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to @MonkeyZeus and @FunkFortyNiner for assistance. 
This was resolved using the following code:

```
<form name="changeImage" method="post" style="padding-bottom: 5%; border-bottom: 1px dotted black; margin-bottom: 5%;" >
<select name="change" id="change" style="width: 97%;">
<?php 
    foreach(glob('images/backgrounds/*.*') as $filename){
        echo '<option value="'.$filename.'">'.$filename.'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="changeBGimage" id="changeBGimage" value="Change BG Image" style="width: 97%;" />

<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['changeBGimage'])) {
        $updateBG = "UPDATE grow_backgroundImage SET filePath = '".$_POST['change']."'";
        $updateBGQuery = $conn->query($updateBG);

        echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';
    }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Well, I think I played *a small part* in this also ;-)

Comment: Absolutely! Edited :) Thank you both very much.

Comment: :-) I find it a bit odd though as to why the id's and certain name attributes would react like that. That's a first time for me.

Comment: oh and you're welcome Cody. Just another note that you might like to be made aware of. If you're going online with this, remember that you can use `glob('images/backgrounds/*.jpg')` or even pass it as an array as it does take additional arguments. Should you happen to have an index file in the same folder, then that too will show up on the dropdown select and potentially cause problems. Unless you're doing something otherwise in `.htaccess`, then I'd go that route.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner That's great information, I will tinker with this! :)

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10591546/  it uses `$files = glob("*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);` and of course there's the manual http://php.net/glob