# how to search files in a directory using 2 words in php

Tags: php, search

In mydirectory

> green.txt
>   black.txt
>   shadow.txt

and my php code

```
<?php
$key = "black+shadow"
$dir = 'file/dir';
$ext = '.txt';
$i=0;
$search = $key;
$results = glob("$dir/*$search*$ext");
if(count($results) != 1) {
    foreach($results as $item) {
      echo $item;
    }
  }?>
```

I want to get the output "black.txt" and "shadow.txt"

Comment: `GLOB_BRACE - Expands {a,b,c} to match 'a', 'b', or 'c' ` mr manual knows all

Comment: @IdontDownVote does not display any results

Comment: Similar Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591530/php-file-listing-multiple-file-extensions Possible duplicate? Pretty close anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$key = "black+shadow";
$dir = "file/dir"
$ext = '.txt';

foreach (explode("+", $key) as $filePart) {
    $fileName = $filePart . $ext;
    if (file_exists("{$dir}/{$fileName}")) {
        echo $fileName . '<br>';
    }
}
```

This assumes that the pattern will always be filepart separated by `+`

You can use `glob` if you end up with more complex solutions - but this is probably the fastest and easiest way to understand IMHO.

Comment: external looping seems rather excessive when glob has an inbuilt mechanism for this

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$key = "{black,shadow}";
$ext = '.txt';
$i=0;
$search = $key;
$results = glob("$search*$ext",GLOB_BRACE);
if(count($results) != 1) {
    foreach($results as $item) {
      echo $item;
    }
  }?>
```

per the manual,

```
GLOB_BRACE - Expands {a,b,c} to match 'a', 'b', or 'c'
```

i added braces around your search terms and added the GLOB_BRACE flag.
(dir removed as i ran a local test)

Comment: You can also use double braces if you want to keep the braces in the glob pattern, `"$dir/{{$search}}$ext"`