# Show All .jpg images and .mp4 files in a directory?

Tags: php, file

I want to list all .jpg images and .mp4 files from a directory onto my website.

So far I have this code which only shows all .jpg files. Could someone please help me amend/improve my code to include .mp4 files also.

```
<?php 
        $directory = "data/profile/$profile_id/main";
        $images = glob($directory . "/*.jpg");

        foreach($images as $image)
        {
            echo '<div id="img"><img src='.$image.' height="100%" width="100%"></div>';

        } ?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP file listing multiple file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591530/php-file-listing-multiple-file-extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php 
  $directory = "data/profile/$profile_id/main";
  $images = glob($directory . "/*.jpg");

  foreach($images as $image)
  {
      echo '<div id="img"><img src='.$image.' height="100%" width="100%"></div>';
  } 

  $videos= glob($directory . "/*.mp4");

  foreach($videos as $video)
  {
      echo '<div id="video"><video width="320" height="240" controls><source src='.$video.' type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></div>';
  }
?>
```

Consider using different ids for each image/video if you'd want to add some behavior to those elements.

Comment: this worked great. the div i've got my images/videos in are 150px by 150px. the video doesnt cover/fill the entire div, not sure if theres a way to crop/zoom the video so it fits/covers the entire div without leaving white space either side. i've already changed the widht/heights to 100% but not doing it. not sure if you can recommend anything?

Comment: managed to solve it. #profile_image_case video {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  background-size:cover;
  flex:0 1 100%;
  object-fit: fill; /* over-ride "object-fit: contain" only for webkit as it doesn't honour the ratio */
}

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$images = glob($directory . "/*.{jpg,mp4}", GLOB_BRACE);
```