How to get file name matches in a directory containing 1 million files
How to get file name matches in a directory containing 1 million files
glob It's slow
File::glob('*')
$files = File::allFiles($path);
$mages=array();
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    
    if ($file->getExtension()==='jpg' or $file->getExtension()==='png' ) {
        $images[]=$file->getPath().'/'.$file->getFilename();
    }


}

What can be done to make it not so slow?
How do I optimize the search?

To start with, your glob should include the file extensions you are look for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10591546/231316

Beyond that, loading a million of anything into memory and then iterating over everything is just something that's going to take time. In the code you provided, after find a file based on rules you are adding to a global array, so that's going to add to your memory footprint. If you have a million files, and 100,000 match your criteria, what are you going to do with that? You can't really show 100,000 things to a user in any fashion that they can work with.

"I put a million things into a bin, how do I arbitrarily pick out a subset without it taking forever?" at this point you need to build an entire system around the bin to pre-compute indexes on the criteria on which you want to search. Live listing/filtering/sorting/etc on a set of one million items is never going to be particularly performant.
